# Update local database with service-base database

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I made similar code with [that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/08/01/windows-phone-7-using-local-database-for-application.aspx) but I also have database on one website and I want each time user go online, it somehow transfer the new data of my service-base database to the local database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [BackgroundWorker for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to fetch the data from your web-service and update the local DB.

You may start the background worker in the App Launched event, call it asynchronously so that app launching won't be delayed.